# window.open("", tabName) returning about:blank with tab name in local storage

Tags: angular, browser, local-storage

I have an angular app where I want to display different pages each in separate  browser tab. I want to be able to have only one open tab for each page. For example if a user clicks to open a page and that page is already open in a tab then it should navigate to the already existing tab otherwise open a new one.
I got that working fine using localStorage. all pages are triggered from the home page here is how I have it working:

in my homepage component I have the following method that gets called every time I open a new page
(note: I am using env variable to distinguish when a user have different app page open for different env)

```
loadGrid(gridId : string)
  {

    let tabName = localStorage.getItem(this.gridEnv+'-'+gridId);
    if(tabName)
    {
      window.open("", tabName).focus;
    }
    else
    {
     let url = "dataGrid/"+gridId;
     localStorage.setItem(this.gridEnv+'-'+gridId, url);
     window.open(url, url).focus();
    }
  }
```

It basically checks to see if I have stored this page in LocalStorage if yes then go to it otherwise create a new tab then store it in LocalStorage.
my local storage will look like this when I have my home page opne and one tab open

```
Storage {local-Home: "hometab", local-1: "dataGrid/1", length: 2}
```

Local-Home is for the home page so that if any of the open pages want to navigate to home this will take them to the already open home page tab

local-1 is one of the pages that is open, if a user tries to open the same page this will take them to the already open tab.

This works great.

Now the problem If a user decided to open another home page in a different tab 
(another http://localhost:4200)
and tries to open one of the pages that are already open from previous home page, I get Blank page. even thought it checks to see if the tab name is already in local storage.

does localstorage care about the parent page? my understanding was window.open("", tabName) should take me to the tab regardless from which parent it was initiated from isn't that the case?
when I open a new home page I don't update the LocalStorage if the another home page is already open. should I clear LocalStorage every time I Open a new Home page? if I do so what will happen to the other open tabs?

Answer (score 0):

You want to be able to have only one open tab for each page.
then you can direct use of navigate function

```
navigate(['your-localstoarge-navigating-component'])
```